# Map the result of a getter with parameter in dart

Tags: collections, dictionary, dart

In Dart I've got

```dart
typedef List<int> Callback(int n);

StyleCallback get fn {
  return (int n) {
    return new List.generate(n, (i) {
      return i;
    });
  };
}
```

I would like to write a getter that gets the result of fn(n) and applies some function f to each element of it. For example, multiplies all elements of the List by 2.

```dart
Callback get myFunc {
    return Iterable.map(fn, (x) => 2 * x);
}
```

But there is not such map functions for collections. Could you please suggest the right way to do it?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Can you add a more concrete  example (doesn't have to actually be valid Dart code). What values do you want to pass, how should the result look like?

Comment: I have still a hard time understanding what you try to accomplish. Maybe you can comment what you want differently than the code in my "answer" does.

Comment: Both `fn` and `(x) =. 2 * x` are functions, so I'm not sure which iterable you want to map over, or what the arguments to `myFunc` are expected to be. Do you want something like: `Callback get myFunc => (n) => fn(n).map((x) => 2 * x);`?

Answer (score 0):

#### Not an answer but I can't possibly put this code in a comment.

You can do something like

```dart
Iterable iter = [1,2,3,4];

int fn(int x) => x * x;

List<String> get myFunc {
  return iter.map((x) => fn(x)).toList();
}

void main() {
  print(myFunc);
}
```

prints

> [1, 4, 9, 16]

but I have no idea where your `typedef` would fit in